# Is there anyway to make chartjs work with csp nonce?

Tags: chart.js

I can't find anything in the documentation. Only [this from github issues](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5208) from 2018 for version 2.x

For now it's already version 4.0. Hope something has changed.

Expected something like [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-security-policy).

Recomendation for any other library that csp compliance are welcome...